# Counting the number of occurrences of a certain month in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a complex problem to solve with SQL query. I need to generate a report that gives a numerical value which represents a number of actions that users performed in each month of the year. For instance, if User1 performed the specified action in January and July, the query needs to return numbers 1 in column called 'January' and 'July' and 0 in columns that represent other month's. The table that I'm pulling the data from has only one column that contains the date and time on which the certain action was taken (this is the only column relevant to this specific problem). I need to make a SQL query that will return this informations for each user in a certain period.
Please help, and if you need any more informations please tell me and I will provide it.
Thanks

The structure of the result should be like this:
User Jan  Feb ..... Dec
UID   1    0         1

I need this for every user that appears in the selected period. My application is using SQL server 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  datepart(month, dateColumn) as Month
,       count(*) as NumberOfActions
from    Actions
group by
        datepart(month, dateColumn)
```

Comment: Looks good, but you only need to group by 'Month' now .. not datepart(month, dateColumn)

Answer (score 0):

The above query is correct, Though this will only return a number for the month.

I would do the following.

```
SELECT  dateparth(month, dateColumn) as Month, count(*) as NumberOfActions
FROM Actions
GROUP BY Month
```

And then (if using php) consider mktime() and date() functions. Like this:

```
/* The year doesn't matter. we are just trying to format this in to a date */
    $date = mktime(0, 0, 0, $row->Month, 1, 2012); 

/* This will display 'Jan, Feb, Mar ...' respectively */
    $dateText = date('M', $date);
```

If using another language then just google alternatives. It'll be the same principle .. just a different syntax.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This will return the data in rows but I think the OP is actually asking for it in columns. You will need a `PIVOT` statement for this, something like this...

Assuming...

```
Create Table TestPivot (UserName Varchar(10), DateColumn DateTime);
```

Then...

```
Select *
  From (Select UserName, DateName(Month, DateColumn) As Month_Name, Count(*) As Month_Count
          From TestPivot
         Group By UserName, DateName(Month, DateColumn)) As SourcePart
  Pivot (Sum(Month_Count)
         For Month_Name In (January, February, March, April, May, June, 
                            July, August, September, October, November, December)) As PivotPart
```

Comment: Hm, is there a way to do it without creating a new table, I'm using my clients database and I don't have the permission to create/delete tables

Comment: That's for example purposes only you will need to amend the script to put your table and column names in. If you want specific code for your specific real world scenario then you will need to amend your question and give us that information.

Comment: It might also be useful if you could say what database your are using, E.g. SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL etc

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005, I'll edit my question so you can see the structure that I need.